# how to have google apps engine send mail- not send a copy of the mail to the sender

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendmail

I'm using GAE send mail- but I dont want the sender of the mail to get a coppy of the mail.
as for now, when a user is sending mail he gets a mail saying that he sent a mail to someone and the body of the sent mail, how do I disable that?

Comment: -1 Shady. I can't think of a legitimate reason for sending mail on behalf of someone without them being aware that it's been sent.

Comment: its a mail being sent to a manager by an employee- to aprove his reported working hours, i want the mail to contain a link to the where the manager can approve it.and thats why i dont want the employee to recive the link

Comment: Apologies. I've been seeing a lot of people asking how to do things that are shady/unethical/illegal using Google App Engine, and it's starting to concern me. Withdrew my -1. You should share more context when you are asking questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.  Sending email from someone without their knowledge isn't permitted by App Engine.

You can send email from any administrator address; you could add a "donotreply@yourapp.com" type address as an administrator and send email from that address.